# PATH problem during RedCloth installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, path, redcloth

I'm trying to run "bundle install" and it tries to install RedCloth. But it seems like theres a problem during the installation because of my path variable. When I tried "gem install RedCloth" I had the exact same error.

I truly dont know what I'm supposed to do with my PATH variable.

http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/613/bad4f6afda58444fa77707b.png

My current PATH variable is **"%APPDATA%\Python\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\"**

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Ruby Installer dev kit.

Download the "development kit" here: http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads

And follow these instructions: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit