# RedCloth Installation failed

Tags: ruby, redcloth

i was trying to install octopuses, but i got stuck installing RedCloth (http://redcloth.org). I think the problem is the same of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797707/path-problem-during-redcloth-installation), but that's the solution for windows and i run OSX (10.8).

--redacted--

Comment: One of these might work for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856460/build-extensions-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-geminstaller

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222388/redcloth-makefile-error-when-trying-to-run-bundle-install-for-octopress

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119138/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-when-install-redcloth-4-2-9-install-linux

Comment: the symlink method worked, thanks a lot.

Comment: I am glad. For anyone else running across this entry the specific answer he found was on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119138/failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-when-install-redcloth-4-2-9-install-linux

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the ruby1.9.1-dev package from Synaptic, or using apt-get.

In a command prompt:

`sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev`

and then:
if you are using Bundler gem, which I suppose, you can type `bundle install` to install it, otherwise you can manually install it via `gem install RedCloth`